# Time Complexity of dependent nested loops

Tags: time-complexity

I'm recently in to the algorithms and I'm having trouble finding the time complexity(Big-Oh notation) of the following algorithm:

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
for(int j=i;j<=n;j=j/2){
for(int k=0;k<=n;k=k*2){
//set of statements
}}}
```

Can anyone help me to determine the complexity of the following algorithm.
I found the inner loop(k-loop) to be independent and it's complexity is (log n).when finding the i,j loop it sort of put me in confusion that what sequence it will become when j=j/2?

Comment: It seems that the two inner loops will run indefinitely. For the second loop, the value of j doesn't increase, while for the third loop, k remains 0 each iteration

Comment: The program never ends, so it has *no* $O$ complexity.